# I keep getting a bunch of extra characters at the end of my C-String

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

I'm doing a school assignment in which I have to read from a file into a dynamically allocated array of structures. I can only use C Style strings and pointer array syntax (i.e. ***(pointer + x)**) for all arrays. I have gotten to a point where I'm trying to load everything into their spots, but when I do this, there is always trash at the end of my **word** variable. How do fix this     issue?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct Pieces
{
    char* word;
    int jump;
};

void reset(char*, int);
int strLen(char*);
void createArr(char*, char*);

int main()
{
    Pieces* cip;
    char* temp;
    ifstream input;
    int numWords, numKeys;

    temp = new char[20];
    input.open("Project4Data.txt");
    input >> numWords;
    input >> numKeys;
    cip = new Pieces[numWords];
    for(int x = 0; x < numWords; x++)
    {
        int tempSize;
        reset(temp, 20);
        input >> temp;
        tempSize = strLen(temp);
        //cout << temp << " ";
        (cip + x)->word = new char[tempSize];
        //cout << tempSize;
        reset((cip + x)->word, tempSize);
        createArr((cip + x)->word, temp);
        input >> (cip + x)->jump;
        //cout << (cip + x)->word<<  << endl;
    }
    input.close();

    //cout << (cip + 2)->word;
    delete[] cip;
    return 0;
}

int strLen(char* word)
{
    int s = 0;
    //cout << word;
    for(int x = 0; *(word + x) != '\0'; x++)
        s++;
    return s;
}

void reset(char* arr, int size)
{
    for(int x = 0; x  < size; x++)
        *(arr + x) = '\0';
}

void createArr(char* a, char* b)
{
    reset(a, strLen(b));
    for(int x = 0; x < strLen(b); x++)
        *(a + x) = *(b + x);
        cout << a;
}
```

When I send ***(cip + x)->word*** and **temp** to **createArr** so that the valid contents of **temp** may be copied onto **(cip + x)->word**, ***(cip + x)->word** always comes out with a ton of trash at the end, despite me setting everything in it to null and only using the first couple indexes. How do I fix this?

The data file has this info on it:

23
11

Java 2 linux 3 fear 0 pool 2 do 0 red 1 lock. 1 I 0 random 2 computers, 0 not 0 the 0 open 2 car! 2 C, 0 lack 0 of 0 dog 1 green 2 C++ 0 bottle 2 wrong, 2 them. 0

Comment: In `createArr` go with `x <= strLen(b)` to copy the 0-char terminator. Or insert a`*(a+strLen(b))=0` at the end of the `for` cycle. Of course, make sure `a` has enough space and better use a local var to store the length of `b` rather than iterating it every time you need its length.

Answer (score 0):

C style strings are null terminated, so the character after the final printable one needs to be equal to 0, or '\0'.
You can set this manually after the loop, or do as Adrian said and replace the less than with a less than/equal to.

```
void createArr(char* a, char* b)
{
    reset(a, strLen(b));
    for(int x = 0; x < strLen(b); x++)
        *(a + x) = *(b + x);
        *(a + x) = *(b + x);
        cout << a;
}
```

or (Probably neater)

```
  void createArr(char* a, char* b)
    {
        reset(a, strLen(b));
        for(int x = 0; x <= strLen(b); x++)
            *(a + x) = *(b + x);
            cout << a;
    }
```